# Swapping columns in a numpy array by a given indexs

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to change column position of a matrix by a given indexs of array

```
import numpy as np 
t = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]) 

indexs = np.array([3, 4, 2, 1, 0]) 

check = [False for i in range(len(indexs))]

for i in range(len(indexs)):
    check[i] = True
    if (i != indexs[i] and check[indexs[i]] == False):
        check[indexs[i]] = True
        t[:, [i, indexs[i]]] = t[:, [indexs[i], i]]
    
print(t)
```

The result I want:

```
[[3 4 2 1 0]
 [3 4 2 1 0]
 [3 4 2 1 0]
 [3 4 2 1 0]]
```

I want to return an array whose column positions is the same as indexs but I can't.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just index the array along the dimension you want:

```
t[:, indexs]
```

Answer (score -1):

if you transpose the matrix it's easy

```
transposed = t.T

result = np.array([transposed[i] for i in indexs])

result = result.T


array([[3, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [3, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [3, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [3, 4, 2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: You can just index the dimension you want: no need to transpose. Any time you find yourself doing a loop and reassembling an array in numpy, you're probably doing it wrong.